# Mysql several columns for polymorphic relationship - feasible?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, polymorphic-associations

I have several 'modules'(at the moment , 4) , each of which has its own table.

I want to implement a tag system for all these modules. Tags will have a many to many relationship between each module respectively.

To implement this polymorphic relationship, i thought of creating a pivot table like this:

tag_name|module_1_id | module_2_id| module_3_id |module_4_id... so on.

any row of this tag_module pivot table will have a valid fk to exactly one module_id and the rest will be set to null.

My question is, is this an extremely hazardous way to go about this implementation ? are there any ways that are far better than this to get what I want ?

How can I ensure uniqueness of a tag_name with a module_N_id , meaning a particular item from a particular module should have a specific tag assigned to it only once ?

Also, over time, the number of modules will increase , so in the future , its possible that the number of columns will be 10,20 even 50. Will this kind of implementation prevent this kind of growth?

Answer (score 1):

Just simply create a table with module id and tag name fields and create a multi-column unique index on these 2 columns (you can add any other field to the table). The multi column unique index will allow you to associate the same tag name with multiple modules, but will prevent you from assigning the same tag name to the same module multiple times.

Comment: okay, so tag_id +module_1_id+module_2_id .....module_N_id will all be unique ?
Aside of that, are there any problems with going with this kind of design ?

Comment: I do not really understand your question.

Comment: i mean to ask if this design has any serious performance issues or problems ? 
will Increasing the number of columns to 30 slow down performance?

Comment: You should not have 30 fields. 2 are sufficient, plus perhaps a few more for purposes like created by, last changed  by. The problem with your design is that if you add a new model, you need to alter your table's structure.

Comment: I don't understand your schema suggestion. Will it have atleast N+1 columns where N is the number of modules ?

Comment: No. It would have 2 columns only: module id and tag name. You do not need more.

Comment: But there are different tables for each module. How will the pivot table know which module that Id is referring to?

Comment: Through the module id field. And my suggestion is not to use a pivot table. You can actually generate the pivot table from the data structure I'm proposing dynamically. for reporting purposes, if required.

Comment: There is no table called module. I have several modules that each have an id

Comment: 1. You should have a module table 2. Still you can store the module's id in the module id field.

Comment: Could you please show a schema of what you're saying? I can't seem to understand your design

Comment: The schema is in the answer.